# Set Profile or NamingConvention for AutoMapper dynamic/object mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper to map either from an object or dynamic. I need to set the naming convention to PascalCaseNamingConvention and I need to get AutoMapper flattening to work (dynamic/object contains a nested object). I'm having trouble with this. Any workarounds or tips?

For ex:

```
object: id, name, summary { score }
destination: Id, Name, SummaryScore
```

Comment: what is `summary { score }`?

Comment: nested object. in usual cases, AutoMapper can map a nested object with flattening. not sure how to get this working with dynamic/object

Comment: With dynamic and object? Or just object? Will you never know the actual type?

Comment: I can make it either... I'm parsing unknown complex json to either object or dynamic.. whichever will work with AutoMapper